# Can two decomposition groups corresponding different prime ideal over same prime equal?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $L$ be a splitting field of the polynomial $X^3-19$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e $L=\mathbb{Q}[\omega,\sqrt[3]{19}]$, where $\omega=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$.

Then we can check that $Gal(L/Q)\cong S_3$.

Moreover, with some computation, we can check that $3\mathcal{O}_L=P^2Q^2R^2$, where $P,Q,R$ are prime ideals of $\mathcal{O}_L$.

Now consider the decomposition fields $L_{\mathcal{D}_P},L_{\mathcal{D}_Q},L_{\mathcal{D}_R}$, i.e fixed fields of the each decomposition group.

From well known theory, each decomposition field has a degree 3 over $\mathbb{Q}$.

On the other hands, there are three subfields of $L$ which have degree 3 over $\mathbb{Q}$, namely $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{19}],\mathbb{Q}[\omega\sqrt[3]{19}],\mathbb{Q}[\omega^2\sqrt[3]{19}]$.

Then author said that any one of them can be the decomposition field, depending on which prime over 3 is being considered.

I don't understand this and what I thought is as follows:

$L_{\mathcal{D}_P}=\mathbb{Q}[\omega^i\sqrt[3]{19}]$ for some $i=1,2,3$.

From well known theory, there exists $\sigma\in Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$ such that $Q=\sigma P$. Then we can check that $L_{\mathcal{D}_Q}=\sigma L_{\mathcal{D}_P}$.

How to guarantee that $\sigma \mathbb{Q}[\omega^i\sqrt[3]{19}]=\mathbb{Q}[\omega^j\sqrt[3]{19}]$ with $i\neq j$?

More generally, let $L$ be a finite galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Let $p$ be a prime number and assume that $P,Q$ are different prime ideals of $\mathcal{O}_L$ lying over $p$. Then should it be $\mathcal{D}_P\neq\mathcal{D}_Q$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three key points here, one of which is special to the $S_3$ situation.

1. if we conjugate the decomposition group of $\mathfrak{P}$ by $\sigma$, we get the decomposition group of $\sigma(\mathfrak{P})$: $D_{\sigma(\mathfrak{P})}=\sigma D(\mathfrak{P})\sigma^{-1}$
2. The Galois group acts transitively on the set of all prime ideals above a fixed prime $p$
3. For $S_3$, all order $2$ subgroups of $S_3$ are conjugate.

From these three statements, one can infer that the decomposition subgroups for the ideals above $3$ are all distinct.

In general, though this is not true: consider for instance the case where $p$ splits completely, then every decomposition group for a prime above $p$ is the trivial subgroup, thus they are all the same.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! From some computation, I can check that $\sigma D(\mathfrak{P})\sigma^{-1}=D(\mathfrak{P})$ iff $\sigma\in D(\mathfrak{P})$ in $S_3$ case so that all decomposition groups being distinct. Is it right conclusion?

Comment: @KSM yes, that's a correct conclusion